# Vectors Subspace Basis / not all linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a matrix
$$A = \begin{vmatrix} a & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & b & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & c & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & d \end{vmatrix} = 0$$

> Edit Note:
>   I want to find all possible real numbers of a,b,c and d that make the vectors (a,1,1,1),(1,b,1,1),(1,1,c,1) and (1,1,1,d) not form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

and they are not all linearly independent.

How do I find all various possible combinations?

What I did:

I tried to use echelon row reduction in order to assume one value then by backward substitution I got the answer, but I couldn't. Also I tried to solve another similar example with one variable, Example: a=b=c=d and that works to me and I got the values.

and I don't know if it's correct to solve it by echelon form or not I'm just guessing because if it's normal numbers I solve it by echelon form.

any help?

Comment: What is the "they" that are not linearly independent?

Comment: why not find the determinant of $A$, and that will tell you where gives $0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I mean the vectors are not linearly independent because it's given that the real numbers are not form Basis of $R^4 which means the vectors are not linearly independent

Comment: @Easy it given a matrix not determinant, please anyone change it to matrix if you can.

Comment: @Rayanh, even it is a matrix only, my method doesn't lose any sense. And the precise term you should use for describing your matrix is "nondegenerate" or "nonsingular" ..

Comment: @Easy I tried what you said but I ended up with one equation has 4 unknowns then how can I find all possible values? if I assume one value I will be able to get the other values but not all possible values!

Comment: Rayanh, you say "the vectors are not linearly independent" but I don't see any vectors, just a $4\times4$ matrix. Which vectors? What do you mean by "all various possible combinations"? Combinations of what?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I want to find all possible real numbers of a,b,c and d that make the vectors (a,1,1,1),(1,b,1,1),(1,1,c,1) and (1,1,1,d) not form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Oh! Now your question begins to make more sense, @Rayanh . Of course, Gerry, Henning knew what you mean, but we must try *much harder* to be more clear and accurate...

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry about that and thank you for your advice I will edit the question thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In order to describe this set, it is necessary and sufficient to calculate the determinant of $A$ using your favorite method and equate it to zero. This gives the equation $$ abcd -ab-ac-ad-bc-bd-cd+2(a+b+c+d)-3=0,$$
which describes a three-dimensional quartic surface in the parameter space $\mathbb{R}^4$. This is the set you are looking for.

Comment: that is exactly what I found. But the question is; How do I find all possible values? I guessed a number as 1 and that works but I can't guess all numbers! is there anyway to find all possible values? and how I do know how many possible values do I have?